# OOP Best Way To Call Similar Functions

Tags: c++, oop

**Background**:
I have 2 similar blocks of code that I would like to merge together in a function. One block is for the x axis and the other is for the y axis. I have had this similar issue multiple times before and have shrugged it off since I assumed there was no better way of merging these in a clean fashion.

**Problem**:
How do I make a function that can replace both snippets of code below in the least number of lines?

**Code**:

```
    //rows
    vector<float> rowSpectrum;
    float tempVal;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROI.size().height; i++) {
        tempVal = cv::mean(cleanImg.row(i)).val[0];
        rowSpectrum.push_back(tempVal);
    }

    //columns
    vector<float> colSpectrum;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROI.size().width; i++) {
        tempVal = cv::mean(cleanImg.col(i)).val[0];
        colSpectrum.push_back(tempVal);
    }
```

Comment: What type is `cleanImg` and do you have access to that?

Comment: @bitmask it's a Mat type and no I do not :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
auto calcSpectrum = [&](int size, cv::Mat (cv::Mat::*memFn)(int) const) {
    vector<float> spectrum;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        auto tempVal = cv::mean((cleanImg.*memFn)(i)).val[0];
        spectrum.push_back(tempVal);
    }
    return spectrum;
}

auto rowSpectrum = calcSpectrum(ROI.size().height, &cv::Mat::row);
auto colSpectrum = calcSpectrum(ROI.size().width, &cv::Mat::col);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer I think, but I'd add the possibility for more complex situations: you can accept a `dataGetter` lambda in `calcSpectrum` lambda and call it to have `.row(i)` or `.column(i)` from `i`.

Comment: @krisz I am new to c++ and would like to research and learn how the first line works. Do you know what it is called so I can google it myself?

Comment: @CarlosCuartas You can search for "lambda" and "member function pointer".